# Bind CheckBox to SelectedItem in ListBox

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-store-apps, selecteditem

I have created a ListBox in WPF, which does the following:

It binds to a DataSource in my ViewModel. The ListBox contains Items and next to each item is a CheckBox. If the user clicks on a CheckBox, the Item is being selected and the Command will be executed. It works fine and the code for WPF looks like this:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding OCAntwort}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAntwort}" >
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <!--ElementName=Window is the Name of the XAML (in root definition)-->
                                    <CheckBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=Window}" Command="{Binding CheckAnswer}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=cbox, Path=IsChecked}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}" x:Name="cbox" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>
```

Now I'm trying the same on Windows Store App, but there's no AncestorType... If I'm doing it like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Name="lbitem">

<CheckBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=Window}" Command="{Binding CheckAnswer}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=cbox, Path=IsChecked}" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=lbitem, Path=IsSelected}" x:Name="cbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

The Checkbox disappears and it'll just display the ItemsSource of OCAntwort. Clicking on an item won't execute the Command of the CheckBox (since there is no CheckBox).
Doing it like this:

```
IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=lbitem, Path=IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
```

would display the CheckBox and execute the Command, but it's not being binded to the SelectedItem.

How can I bind the CheckBox (which is being displayed next to the ListBoxItem for each ListBoxItem) to the SelectedItem of a ListBox? Working code is above... I want that the code should work in my Windows Store App (and later in my Windows Phone App).

Example:

You can download a sample here: http://weblogs.asp.net/marianor/archive/2008/02/04/multiselect-listview-with-checkboxes-in-wpf.aspx

This shows what I want to achieve in Windows Store App.

Edit: Doing it like this displays the ListBox with a content and a CheckBox, but I still need to bind the CheckBox by the SelectedItem. Means when the user clicks on a CheckBox, the ListBoxItem has to be selected or if the user clicks on a ListBoxItem, the CheckBox has to be selected.

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding OCAntwort}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAntwort}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="listBox" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you've found the solution yet but I have used the following code to establish two way binding between the `IsChecked` property of a `CheckBox` and the `IsSelected` property of a parent `ListBoxItem` or `ListViewItem`.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but I've already solved the solution (but I forgot how :-( ). I've worked in a company (currently not working there anymore), so unfortunately I can't get the code for it... But I think I've also tried to solve it somehow with AncestorType or FindAncestor and guess it didn't work or I couldn't even use it in the XAML-code for Windows Store/Phone... Anyway, thanks for helping out. By the way, your code is almost the same code as the one on the link in my first post?..

Answer (score 0):

You should use TemplatedParent as you are writing inside the ListBoxItem.

```
IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=lbitem, 
            Path=IsSelected,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
```

I think this may resolve your problem.

Comment: Already tried this before, doesn't work. CheckBox will be displayed, but not with the SelectedItem/ItemsSource, which means I can execute the Command by clicking on a CheckBox, but I can't access the SelectedItem + XAML only displays the CheckBox and not the ItemsSource (It normally looks like this: **[ ] Item1**     _[ ] = CheckBox, Item1 = ListBoxItem_)